# Why does upsert a record using update_one raise ValueError?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to add a record to the collection if the key doesn't already exist. I understand [MongoDB][1] offers the `upsert`for this so I did a

```
db.collection.update({"_id":"key1"},{"_id":"key1"},True)
```

This seems to work.

However in the [Pymongo documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?_ga=1.96647199.1473856847.1458939091#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) it says that update is deprecated and use to `update_one()`.

But:

```
db.collection.update_one({"_id":"key1"},{"_id":"key1"},True)
```

Gives:

```
raise ValueError('update only works with $ operators')
ValueError: update only works with $ operators
```

I don't really understand why `update_one` is different and why I need to use a `$` operator. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is because you didn't specify any [update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/).
For example to [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) the `id` value use:

```
db.collection.update_one({"_id":"key1"}, {"$set": {"id":"key1"}}, upsert=True)
```

Note that in the Mongo shell, this will simply replace the document with the new document.

Answer (score 40):

Use `replace_one()` instead of `update_one()`. the 3rd parameter of `replace_one()` is `upsert`, too.

```
db.collection.replace_one({"_id": "key1"}, {"_id": "key1"}, True)
```

My personal opinion is this implementation of `update_one()` is inconsistent with the behaviour of MongoDB client. The `upsert` option in `update_one()` is actually meaningless. But the developers of pyMongo may just want to use this to distinguish `update_one()` and `replace_one()`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer saved me a lot of headache. It was unclear from the docs that the same call with `update_one` is invalid and `replace_one` is. Applies to the C++ driver, too, by the way.

Comment: They are different. Replace_one always replace the data, update_one can update some fields of the record.